# Using Doxygen to output Javadoc

Tags: javadoc, doxygen, jsdoc3

I am trying to generate Typescript definitions for the LibreOffice SDK, which uses Doxygen to generate its documentation.

Currently, I am using Doxygen to output XML, and parsing the XML to generate the JsDoc comments. However, I find myself having to handle manually each element, in order to get a format similar to JavaDoc. I assume it would be simpler to map JavaDoc to JsDoc, then to parse the XML into JsDoc.

**Is it possible to configure Doxygen to output Javadoc?**

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: Please put questions in the original question to extend the question and not in a comment. No to the best of my knowledge doxygen cannot out javadoc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No to the best of my knowledge doxygen cannot output javadoc.
See the doxygen documentation for the available output formats (http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/output.html)